# checkbox in front of each treeView node

Tags: html, checkbox, treeview

I am trying to create a `treeView` inside an HTML table and want to put **in front of each node** a **checkbox** for each access **column**.

This my HTML code:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Object
        </th>
        <th>
            access 1
        </th>
        <th>
            access 2
        </th>
        <th>
            access 3
        </th>
        <th>
            access 4
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="4">
            <div id="m_tree_1" class="tree-demo">
                <ul>
                    <li id="module1">
                        module 1
                        <ul>
                            <li data-jstree='{ "icon" : "fa fa-crosshairs m--font-focus " }'>
                                <span class="m--font-bold">
                                    Entity
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li data-jstree='{ "icon" : "fa fa-crosshairs m--font-focus " }'>
                                <span class="m--font-bold">
                                    Entity
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li data-jstree='{ "icon" : "fa fa-crosshairs m--font-focus " }'>
                                <span class="m--font-bold">
                                    Entity
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li data-jstree='{ "icon" : "fa fa-crosshairs m--font-focus " }'>
                                <span class="m--font-bold">
                                    Entitée
                                </span>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="module2">
                        module 2
                        <ul>
                            <li data-jstree='{ "icon" : "fa fa-crosshairs m--font-focus " }'>
                                <span class="m--font-bold">
                                    Entity
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li data-jstree='{ "icon" : "fa fa-crosshairs m--font-focus " }'>
                                <span class="m--font-bold">
                                    Entity
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li data-jstree='{ "icon" : "fa fa-crosshairs m--font-focus " }'>
                                <span class="m--font-bold">
                                    Entity
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li data-jstree='{ "icon" : "fa fa-crosshairs m--font-focus " }'>
                                <span class="m--font-bold">
                                    Entitée
                                </span>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="module3">
                        module 3
                        <ul>
                            <li data-jstree='{ "icon" : "fa fa-crosshairs m--font-focus " }'>
                                <span class="m--font-bold">
                                    Entity
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li data-jstree='{ "icon" : "fa fa-crosshairs m--font-focus " }'>
                                <span class="m--font-bold">
                                    Entity
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li data-jstree='{ "icon" : "fa fa-crosshairs m--font-focus " }'>
                                <span class="m--font-bold">
                                    Entity
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li data-jstree='{ "icon" : "fa fa-crosshairs m--font-focus " }'>
                                <span class="m--font-bold">
                                    Entitée
                                </span>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </th>
        <input for="administrationModule" type="checkbox">
    </tr>





</tbody>
```

I am trying to create for each treeview node a check box by each column, like in the image below:

[image]

Comment: From a quick view what have you tried?  It looks like you could put a checkbox for each access column for each entity right in the code.  You would have to have proper placement but the rest is all CSS.  Also there are all other kinds of things you can do as well, like creating a web component to inject for each column which would make this cleaner as well but a bit more advanced.

Comment: My problem is that I can't create in front of each entity it's checkbox.
For example, for section 1, I have 4 entities, so I want to create in front of these 4 entities 4 checkboxes and all these checkboxes to be attached to column access 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zpfamxx7/5/) for you to review.  You have multiple use cases in your question here.  But not much detail to go by.  If you want to certain events to happen upon clicking then you should show more of a sample on what you've done.  Your example states that you wrote a HTML table only, you need a back end to handle the events, what libraries have you tried (jQuery, Angular, etc.).  The JSFiddle will provide you with a layout and a single click event.  I hope it helps it should be enough to get started.

Here is the HTML have to go to fiddle for the rest:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
      </th>
      <th>
        access 1
      </th>
      <th>
        access 2
      </th>
      <th>
        access 3
      </th>
      <th>
        access 4
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4">
        <div id="m_tree_1" class="tree-demo">
          <ul>
            <li id="module1">
              module 1
              <ul class="accessOne">
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  <span class="m--font-bold">Entity1</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  <span class="m--font-bold">Entity2</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  <span class="m--font-bold">Entity3</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  <span class="m--font-bold">Entitée</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="module2">
              module 2
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  <span class="m--font-bold">Entity1</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  <span class="m--font-bold">Entity2</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  <span class="m--font-bold">Entity3</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  <span class="m--font-bold">Entitée</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="module3">
              module 3
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  <span class="m--font-bold">Entity1</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  <span class="m--font-bold">Entity2</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  <span class="m--font-bold">Entity3</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  <span class="m--font-bold">Entitée</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <input id="checkOne" name="checkOne" for="administrationModule" type="checkbox">
      </th>
      <th>
        <input for="administrationModule" type="checkbox">
      </th>
      <th>
        <input for="administrationModule" type="checkbox">
      </th>
      <th>
        <input for="administrationModule" type="checkbox">
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dylan Wright.
I appreciate your effort
Thanks for your time and helping me

Comment: No problem hope it helps